# Show a div completely inside a overflow hidden parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, overflow

I have a div `.div1` which is `overflow :hidden`.
It contains a link of say `user A` when someone hovers over it . A `.seek` div is created and appended to parent div of link `a`. I.e. `.div1` using  jquery.
Since `.seek` is child of `.div1`

```
$(.div1).mouseleave(function{
       seek.remove();
      //removes seek div.
})
```

but as `.div1` is overflow hidden some parts of `.seek` gets hidden.   How can i prevent this?

Seek is used to seek through user profiles without opening the whole page. A feature similar to google+.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want to achieve, can you please create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem?

Comment: when the element is removed there may not stay any elements i.e. hidden too....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show an oveflowing child element of a parent with `overflow: hidden;` if you change it's position to :

```
position:absolute;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/LLaLy/)**

Comment: Making the parent div non-deafult ie. `relative` or `absolute` got my prob solved